# Mapping a 32 bit image to a 32 bit process from a 64 bit application

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, code-injection, dll-injection

I'm trying to figure out a way to map (either through loadlibrary or preferably manually) a 32bit image (dll) into a 32bit process from a 64bit running application. Any ideas?

Currently, injection/mapping everything looks like it's working, but when testing with an empty dll that just creates a message box, it doesn't actually create the messagebox. The injection works fine when coming from a 32bit application.

Here is how I've tested with LoadLibrary

```
EnsureElevation( ); // ensures that we're run as admin and that we have debug privs

// messy code because it's test code
LPVOID LoadLib = ( LPVOID )GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA( "kernel32.dll" ), "LoadLibraryA" );

HANDLE Proc = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, GetProcessID( L"target.exe" ) );
std::cout << Proc << '\n';
std::cout << "Proc Error: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError( ) << '\n'; // 0x0

LPVOID RemoteString = VirtualAllocEx( Proc, NULL, strlen( R"(C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MessageBox.dll)" ), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
std::cout << RemoteString << '\n';
std::cout << "String Error: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError( ) << '\n'; // 0x0

std::cout << WriteProcessMemory( Proc, RemoteString, R"(C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MessageBox.dll)", strlen( R"(C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MessageBox.dll)" ), NULL ) << '\n';
std::cout << "Write Error: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError( ) << '\n'; // 0x0

std::cout << CreateRemoteThread( Proc, NULL, NULL, ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE )LoadLib, ( LPVOID )RemoteString, NULL, NULL ) << '\n';
std::cout << "Create Error: 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError( ) << '\n'; // 0x0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateRemoteThread 32->64 and/or 64->32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494284/createremotethread-32-64-and-or-64-32)

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805239/mapping-a-32bit-image-to-a-32bit-process-from-a-64bit-application

Comment: `LoadLib` this is address in 64bit kernel32.dll when you need address inside 32-bit kernel32.dll

Answer (score 5):

when thread created inside wow64 process it anyway begin execute in 64bit mode - from `LdrInitializeThunk` inside 64-bit `ntdll.dll`.

inside this, when process is wow64, the `Run64IfContextIs64` function is called - system try determinate - are thread must execute in native or wow64 context. this is done by checking tread start address - if it is within a native dll (currently this is `ntdll.dll`, `wow64.dll`, `wow64win.dll`, `wow64cpu.dll` ) - system run it in native (64 bit mode). call graph is

[image]

and in debugger we can see next debug print:

```
<pid>:<tid> Found inside *.dll
<pid>:<tid> InitialPC <rip> is within a native dll.  Running native context unchanged.
```

special case is InitialPC was inside 64-bit kernel32.dll or 64-bit user32.dll (look for `DllsToRemap` ) - inside `Run64IfContextIs64` called `MapContextAddress64TO32` system check address inside native dll. in some case (say for `DebugBreak`) system try redirect this to 32bit kernel32.dll `DebugBreak` and execute in wow64 mode, but.. here bug - crashed. in most case - system redirect address from 64-bit `kernel32.dll` (or `user32.dll` ) to `Wow64pBreakPoint` (not exported function) inside `wow64.dll`. this function executed in native (64-bit mode) - call `int 3` (breakpoint) if debugger attached. after this simply terminate thread. in debug output we can view

```
<pid>:<tid> InitialPC <rip> found in the space reserved for 64-bit kernel32.dll
```

this is however exactly your case - you pass address of `LoadLibraryA` inside 64-bit `kernel32.dll`. which of course is error.

otherwise (if PC not inside 64-bit module) - system execute this thread in wow64 context, what we and need here

[image]

```
<pid>:<tid> ThunkStartupContent64TO32: Original InitialPC <rip>, StartupAddress <eip>, Arg1 <pv>
<pid>:<tid> ThunkStartupContext64TO32: Thunking RTL user thread start
```

after `BTCpuSimulate` thread go to the `LdrInitializeThunk` from 32-bit ntdll.dll and execute as usual in wow64 context.

---

so we need instead address of `LoadLibraryA` inside 64-bit `kernel32.dll` got address of `LoadLibraryW` inside 32-bit `kernel32.dll`. however this task is not simply if try use only documented win32 api. i use for this ntdll api (and some of this not documented). however as is:

```
PVOID getRVA(PVOID Base, ULONG_PTR BaseAddress, PCSTR Name)
{
    if (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 pinth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)RtlImageNtHeader(Base))
    {
        BaseAddress -= pinth->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

        DWORD Size, exportRVA;
        if (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pied = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)
            RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(Base, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, &Size))
        {
            exportRVA = RtlPointerToOffset(Base, pied);

            DWORD NumberOfFunctions = pied->NumberOfFunctions;
            DWORD NumberOfNames = pied->NumberOfNames;

            if (0 < NumberOfNames && NumberOfNames <= NumberOfFunctions)
            {
                PDWORD AddressOfFunctions = (PDWORD)RtlOffsetToPointer(Base, pied->AddressOfFunctions);
                PDWORD AddressOfNames = (PDWORD)RtlOffsetToPointer(Base, pied->AddressOfNames);
                PWORD AddressOfNameOrdinals = (PWORD)RtlOffsetToPointer(Base, pied->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

                DWORD a = 0, b = NumberOfNames, o;

                do 
                {
                    o = (a + b) >> 1;

                    int i = strcmp(RtlOffsetToPointer(Base, AddressOfNames[o]), Name);

                    if (!i)
                    {
                        DWORD Rva = AddressOfFunctions[AddressOfNameOrdinals[o]];
                        return (ULONG_PTR)Rva - (ULONG_PTR)exportRVA < Size ? 0 : RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseAddress, Rva);
                    }

                    0 > i ? a = o + 1 : b = o;

                } while (a < b);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

PVOID GetWowLoadLibraryW()
{
    PVOID pv = 0;
    STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "\\KnownDlls32\\kernel32.dll");
    HANDLE hSection;

    if (0 <= ZwOpenSection(&hSection, SECTION_QUERY|SECTION_MAP_READ, &oa))
    {
        SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION sii;
        if (0 <= ZwQuerySection(hSection, SectionImageInformation, &sii, sizeof(sii), 0))
        {
            PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
            SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;
            if (0 <= ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READONLY))
            {
                __try {
                    pv = getRVA(BaseAddress, (ULONG_PTR)sii.TransferAddress, "LoadLibraryW");

                } __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
                }
                ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress);
            }
        }
        NtClose(hSection);
    }

    return pv;
}
```

after this task became trivial:

```
if (PVOID wowLoadLibraryW = GetWowLoadLibraryW())
{
    //PCWSTR szLibPath = ...

    SIZE_T s = (wcslen(szLibPath) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, <pid>))
    {
        if (PVOID pv = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, s, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE))
        {
            if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pv, szLibPath, s, 0))
            {
                if (HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)wowLoadLibraryW, pv, 0, 0))
                {
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
}
```